# How to change one property (default value) on multiple materials

Tags: materials, emission

When I export an .obj from my Shelfplanning tool and import it into Blender, all my materials have the "Emission Strength" set to `1.0` (and there are 450 materials in total).

How to turn off emission on all my materials, without clicking on them and turning it off manually?

Comment: What do you mean "Emission 1"?

Comment: If I select a material and go into the material properties the emission strength is alway 1 when I import the obj.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script will set all "Emission Strength"s to 0. Copy it into the Text Editor and hit the "Run" button. It will affect all materials in the file, so be careful.

```
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.use_nodes:
        continue
    for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
            n.inputs["Emission Strength"].default_value = 0
```

Normally you do "no emission" with Emission Strength=1 and a black emission color though...

Answer (score -1):

If they have the same material, and after import they have the same own material, then just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Material of object selected you want.

Comment: They all have diffrent materials thats the problem